# Update Rule on View - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, view, rule

My rule to update a view "fva_gpi_sbcpcba_voapcba" isn't properly updating the "product_serial_number" column in both "general_product_info" and "fva_3800" tables.

It only updates the "product_serial_number" in the first table written in the update rule and not both. That is, in this case it will update the fva_3800 table's product_serial_number, but not the general_product_info table's. If I put the UPDATE on general_product_info table first, vice versa.

Update rule: (removed overly long and unimportant code and replaced with ...)

```
CREATE RULE update_fva_fullview
AS ON UPDATE TO fva_gpi_sbcpcba_voapcba
DO INSTEAD
(UPDATE voa_pcba
SET (voa_pcba_serial_number, ..., ch4_voa_cqr_link)
= (NEW.voa_pcba_serial_number, ..., NEW.ch4_voa_cqr_link)
WHERE voa_pcba_serial_number = OLD.voa_pcba_serial_number;
UPDATE sbc_pcba
SET (sbc_pcba_serial_number, sbc_fw_revision, sbc_mac_address, sbc_test_result_link)
= (NEW.sbc_pcba_serial_number, NEW.sbc_fw_revision, NEW.sbc_mac_address, NEW.sbc_test_result_link)
WHERE sbc_pcba_serial_number = OLD.sbc_pcba_serial_number;
UPDATE fva_3800
SET (product_serial_number, status_pcba_serial_number, sbc_pcba_serial_number, voa_pcba_serial_number) 
= (NEW.product_serial_number, NEW.status_pcba_serial_number, NEW.sbc_pcba_serial_number, NEW.voa_pcba_serial_number)
WHERE product_serial_number = OLD.product_serial_number;
UPDATE general_product_info
SET (product_serial_number, part_number, innovator_product_bom, calibration_certificate, manual, 
application_sw_name, application_sw_rev, test_report_link, production_exceptions, notes)
= (NEW.product_serial_number, NEW.part_number, NEW.innovator_product_bom, NEW.calibration_certificate, NEW.manual, 
NEW.application_sw_name, NEW.application_sw_rev, NEW.test_report_link, NEW.production_exceptions, NEW.notes)
WHERE product_serial_number = OLD.product_serial_number;);
```

View: (in full... sorry, it is long, but I'd rather not cause confusion)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW fva_gpi_sbcpcba_voapcba AS
SELECT product_serial_numbers.product_serial_number, general_product_info.part_number, general_product_info.innovator_product_bom, 
general_product_info.calibration_certificate, general_product_info.manual, general_product_info.application_sw_name, 
general_product_info.application_sw_rev, general_product_info.test_report_link, fva_3800.status_pcba_serial_number, 
sbc_pcba.sbc_pcba_serial_number, sbc_pcba.sbc_fw_revision, sbc_pcba.sbc_mac_address, sbc_pcba.sbc_test_result_link, 
voa_pcba.voa_pcba_serial_number, voa_pcba.voa_fw_revision, voa_pcba.voa_test_result_link, voa_pcba.ch1_tap_part_number, 
voa_pcba.ch1_tap_serial_number, voa_pcba.ch1_tap_cqr_link, voa_pcba.ch1_voa_part_number, voa_pcba.ch1_voa_serial_number, 
voa_pcba.ch1_voa_cqr_link, voa_pcba.ch2_tap_part_number, voa_pcba.ch2_tap_serial_number, voa_pcba.ch2_tap_cqr_link, 
voa_pcba.ch2_voa_part_number, voa_pcba.ch2_voa_serial_number, voa_pcba.ch2_voa_cqr_link, voa_pcba.ch3_tap_part_number, 
voa_pcba.ch3_tap_serial_number, voa_pcba.ch3_tap_cqr_link, voa_pcba.ch3_voa_part_number, voa_pcba.ch3_voa_serial_number, 
voa_pcba.ch3_voa_cqr_link, voa_pcba.ch4_tap_part_number, voa_pcba.ch4_tap_serial_number, voa_pcba.ch4_tap_cqr_link, 
voa_pcba.ch4_voa_part_number, voa_pcba.ch4_voa_serial_number, voa_pcba.ch4_voa_cqr_link, general_product_info.production_exceptions, 
general_product_info.notes, general_product_info.gpi_id
FROM product_serial_numbers
INNER JOIN general_product_info ON product_serial_numbers.product_serial_number = general_product_info.product_serial_number
INNER JOIN fva_3800 ON product_serial_numbers.product_serial_number = fva_3800.product_serial_number
INNER JOIN sbc_pcba ON fva_3800.sbc_pcba_serial_number = sbc_pcba.sbc_pcba_serial_number
INNER JOIN voa_pcba ON fva_3800.voa_pcba_serial_number = voa_pcba.voa_pcba_serial_number;
```

product_serial_number is a pkey in product_serial_numbers table, and a unique fkey in general_product_info and fva_3800 tables.

edit:

```
fva_3800_product_serial_number_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_serial_number) REFERENCES product_serial_numbers(product_serial_number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
```

All of the constraints for fkeys are like this. They all have CASCADE and SET NULL.

Here is the definition of fva_3800 table:

```
CREATE TABLE FVA_3800 (
    id serial CONSTRAINT fva_3800_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
    product_serial_number varchar(32) UNIQUE REFERENCES Product_Serial_Numbers(product_serial_number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
    status_PCBA_serial_number varchar(32),
    SBC_PCBA_serial_number varchar(32) REFERENCES SBC_PCBA(SBC_PCBA_serial_number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
    VOA_PCBA_serial_number varchar(32) REFERENCES VOA_PCBA(VOA_PCBA_serial_number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: Can you post the (abbreviated) table definitions? The most likely cause is a referential action (`ON UPDATE CASCADE`?) in the `FOREIGN KEY` clauses of tables `general_product_info` and `fva_3800` to table `product_serial_numbers`.

Comment: I can tell you that the fkey constraints all have ON UPDATE CASCADE and ON DELETE SET TO NULL
I will update with these details on the main post

Comment: Though I just tried changing the two fkey constraints to a simple fkey with no cascade nor set null on both general_product_info and fva_3800 tables, and it still doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Rules, I used Functions and Triggers.

Rules just don't work properly in this situation for UPDATEs nor DELETEs

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_fva_full() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $_$
BEGIN
UPDATE voa_pcba
SET (voa_pcba_serial_number, voa_fw_revision, voa_test_result_link, ch1_tap_part_number, ch1_tap_serial_number, ch1_tap_cqr_link,
ch1_voa_part_number, ch1_voa_serial_number, ch1_voa_cqr_link, ch2_tap_part_number, ch2_tap_serial_number, ch2_tap_cqr_link,
ch2_voa_part_number, ch2_voa_serial_number, ch2_voa_cqr_link, ch3_tap_part_number, ch3_tap_serial_number, ch3_tap_cqr_link,
ch3_voa_part_number, ch3_voa_serial_number, ch3_voa_cqr_link, ch4_tap_part_number, ch4_tap_serial_number, ch4_tap_cqr_link,
ch4_voa_part_number, ch4_voa_serial_number, ch4_voa_cqr_link)
= (NEW.voa_pcba_serial_number, NEW.voa_fw_revision, NEW.voa_test_result_link, NEW.ch1_tap_part_number, NEW.ch1_tap_serial_number, NEW.ch1_tap_cqr_link,
NEW.ch1_voa_part_number, NEW.ch1_voa_serial_number, NEW.ch1_voa_cqr_link, NEW.ch2_tap_part_number, NEW.ch2_tap_serial_number, NEW.ch2_tap_cqr_link,
NEW.ch2_voa_part_number, NEW.ch2_voa_serial_number, NEW.ch2_voa_cqr_link, NEW.ch3_tap_part_number, NEW.ch3_tap_serial_number, NEW.ch3_tap_cqr_link,
NEW.ch3_voa_part_number, NEW.ch3_voa_serial_number, NEW.ch3_voa_cqr_link, NEW.ch4_tap_part_number, NEW.ch4_tap_serial_number, NEW.ch4_tap_cqr_link,
NEW.ch4_voa_part_number, NEW.ch4_voa_serial_number, NEW.ch4_voa_cqr_link)
WHERE voa_pcba_serial_number = OLD.voa_pcba_serial_number;
UPDATE sbc_pcba
SET (sbc_pcba_serial_number, sbc_fw_revision, sbc_mac_address, sbc_test_result_link)
= (NEW.sbc_pcba_serial_number, NEW.sbc_fw_revision, NEW.sbc_mac_address, NEW.sbc_test_result_link)
WHERE sbc_pcba_serial_number = OLD.sbc_pcba_serial_number;
UPDATE fva_3800
SET (product_serial_number, status_pcba_serial_number, sbc_pcba_serial_number, voa_pcba_serial_number) 
= (NEW.product_serial_number, NEW.status_pcba_serial_number, NEW.sbc_pcba_serial_number, NEW.voa_pcba_serial_number)
WHERE product_serial_number = OLD.product_serial_number;
UPDATE general_product_info
SET (product_serial_number, part_number, innovator_product_bom, calibration_certificate, manual, 
application_sw_name, application_sw_rev, test_report_link, production_exceptions, notes)
= (NEW.product_serial_number, NEW.part_number, NEW.innovator_product_bom, NEW.calibration_certificate, NEW.manual, 
NEW.application_sw_name, NEW.application_sw_rev, NEW.test_report_link, NEW.production_exceptions, NEW.notes)
WHERE product_serial_number = OLD.product_serial_number;
RETURN OLD;
END $_$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER update_from_fva_view
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON fva_gpi_sbcpcba_voapcba
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_fva_full();
```